# node.js Отправка письма

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, email, callback

С помощью node.js нужно из формы вытягивать данные и отправлять на почту.
Сервер реализован на express. Данные получаю без проблем.
Для отправки данных на почту использую пакет nodemailer.

Проблема в отправке - письмо не отправляется.
Выдает ошибку следующего содержания:

```
{ Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more
 at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z13sm16002309wrw.19
 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\Project-Portfolio\no
de_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:555:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\Project-Portf
olio\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1244:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\Project
-Portfolio\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:338:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\Project-Portfoli
o\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:702:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\Project-Portfolio\node_mo
dules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:507:14)
    at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\Project-Portfolio\nod
e_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:459:47)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.
7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z13sm16002309wrw.19 - gsm
tp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
```

Показываю свою реализацию отправки.

Файл config.json.
Как я понимаю в поле user нужно указать реальный email, а в поле pass нужно указать пароль от этой почты. Вообщем это я и сделал. Здесь же я конечно заменил.

```
{
    "upload": "public/upload",
    "mail": {
        "subject": "Сообщение с сайта",
        "smtp": {
            "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
            "post": 465,
            "secure": true,
            "auth": {
                "user": "user",
                "pass": "pass"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Файл роута (смотрим на post запрос):

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const config = require("../config.json");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    let obj = {
        title: "Mail"
    };
    res.render("./pages/works", obj);
});

//===== отправка письма на почту =====
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    //требуем наличия имени, обратной почты и текста
    if(!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.text) {
        //если что-либо не указано - сообщить об этом
        return res.json({status: "Укажите данные!"});
    }

//    инициализирум модуль для отправки писем и указываем данные из конфига
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(config.mail.smtp);
    let mailOptions = {
        from: `"${req.body.name}" <${req.body.email}>`,
        to: config.mail.smtp.auth.user,
        subject: config.mail.subject,
        text: req.body.text.trim().slice(0, 500) + `\n Отправлено с: <${req.body.email}>`
    };

    //отправляем почту
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        //если есть ошибки при отправке - сообщаем об этом
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.json({status: "При отправке письма произошла ошибка"});
        }
        res.json({status: "Письмо успешно отправлено"});
    })

});

module.exports = router;
```

Вообщем очень нужна помощь в решении этой проблемы. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В гугл включили `lesssecure`?

Comment: https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps эту опцию нужно включить, чтобы можно было удаленно достучаться к `smtp` гугла. Включите и попробуйте снова отправить.

Comment: Включил - к сожалению ошибка та же.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Ваш совет помог.
Перерыл все англоязычные форумы и ничего не нашел.
Сразу не сработал, поскольку забыл вернуть верные логин и пасс.

Comment: Письма приходят. Интересно почему на почте в поле отправителя всегда указывается "Я"?

Comment: `from` у вас скрипт берет из `req`, то есть, который указал клиент, а нужно указать тот, с которого вы шлете письмо

Comment: Я пробовал указать произвольные, например test@gmail.com, но результат то же.